# Jarallax in wordpress error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use Jarallax in wordpress theme.
I'm getting some errors

First

> TypeError: $.browser is undefined
>
> if($.browser.iDevice){

I moved whole js file into my jscript and getting another error

> TypeError: Jarallax is not a constructor
>
> var jarallax = new Jarallax();

this is my starting code

`var init = function (){
        console.log('started');
        var jarallax = new Jarallax();
    }
    init();`

console gives me 'started' output

Your help is more than needed! mil thanks in advance!
Alexei

Comment: `browser` was deprecated after jQuery 1.3 and removed after jQuery 1.8, so I believe you need to downgrade whatever version of jquery you are using to be compatible with Jarallax

Comment: I copied jarallax.js into my javascript file after jquery deceleration and it loads. What I'm missing ??? Thanks